# Is this array static or dynamic?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, static, malloc

So I'm studying memory allocation and it said that you can only allocate memory dynamically using malloc(); but isn't this dynamic memory allocation too? it works btw.So I'm a bit confused.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int integer,cntr;
    scanf("%d",&integer);
    char words[integer];
    for(cntr = 0;cntr < integer - 1;cntr++)
        words[cntr] = 'k';
    words[cntr] = '\0';
    printf("%s",words);
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).  The size is indeed dynamic, but in practice it'll generally be allocated on the stack instead of the heap (so don't use it for anything too big).

Depending on your compiler and so on, this will probably end up being a lot faster than allocating heap memory, being nothing but an adjustment of the stack pointer.

Variable-length arrays were introduced in the C99 standard, so bear in mind that you won't be able to use them with very old C compilers (such as MSVC).

Comment: Wait I'm confused, so its dynamic? but @jack/*comment below */ because its allocated in the stack instead of heap its still considered static. I thought the definition of dynamic is if memory will be allocated during run-time

Comment: Well, I mean the size is dynamic and determined at runtime.  The stack is still a static chunk of memory, allocated with a finite size when your thread was created.

Comment: So what even though the size is dynamic and determined at runtime, as long as its allocated in the stack and not the heap its still static? Just in case it comes up in a test

Comment: It's generally better to think of it as "dynamic" (ie: manually allocated) and "automatic".  The difference being who's responsible for allocation and deallocation.  With auto storage, the compiler does it (and you're generally not allowed to mess with it); with dynamic storage, you have to `malloc` and `free` stuff yourself.

Comment: @cHao But in a test, what would be the best answer? can't ask my professor cause 2nd term hasn't started yet

Comment: @vincent: The correct answer is "automatic".  It's not dynamic, because you don't have to (and in fact can't) `malloc` it, and it's not static because it's cleaned up when the function ends.  "Static" effectively means "lives til the end of the program".

Answer (score 1):

The array is an ***local array***, and it will ***automatically*** deallocated once the scope(`{`,`}`) in which it is defined ends.
Technically, the standard does not define where it should be allocated but only defines the characteristics such an array has to offer. The standard does not even mention stack or heap.:

Answer (score 0):

This is static because the array is allocated on the *stack* and not on the *heap*.

It's not allocated by the memory manager, it's just reserved on the stack, but nothing more. It ceases to exist (in the sense that using it will provide garbage) as soon as it goes out of scope.

Mind that, since stack is limited, you won't be able to allocate a so big array in this way.

Comment: If it is on the stack, it isn't static. static allocation means that the addresses are fixed for the duration of the program. You can imagine doing static allocation of activation records -- in the absence of recursivity obviously -- and it even was done for instance in the early FORTRAN compiler, but I don't think anybody ever did that for C or C++

Comment: It's somewhat improper to use static for stack allocated objects, I agree with you. But it's not dynamic in proper sense too since it's not managed by any memory allocator, it's just stack reserved. It's considered _automatic_, as eplained in James answer.